# What does 'chee' mean in the following quote?

Tags: vocabulary

I read a very interesting book called '[China in War and Revolution](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XORD7ODG2NUC&pg=PA356&dq=zarrow%20chee&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rXuwVMb4G5HaaoGYgIgN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)' about the period from 1900-1949 in China. I am curious about the meaning of the word 'chee' in the passage below. I don't speak Chinese (at all) and the author doesn't give the character in any case, sorry.

> After the Japanese were defeated and the civil war was under way the
>   CCP faced the possibility of counter-revolution. At least in some
>   areas, in spite of all attempts to soften rural elite opposition over
>   the preceding years, landlords greeted early discussions of coalition
>   government and a return of the Guomindang with glee. One landlord told
>   one of his workers. “Heh! Still pressing us to pay grain tax. Fuck
>   you. Chee! The Guomindang armies will be here in a minute. Gonna cut
>   your little prick off! Chee!"

Edit: the quote is cited to ... where it appears exactly as Zarrow rendered it, still saying 'Chee'. In Esherick's article, it's cited to *Guanyu Yangjiagou de tudi wenti, 1946*.

I googled *this* title and it comes up with *Yangjiagou de tudi wcnti” (On the land problem in Yangjiagou, 9 August 1946, Mizhi Archives, permanent juan 4.*
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ib-sEZzxkb4C&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=Guanyu+Yangjiagou+de+tudi+wenti,+1946&source=bl&ots=9EQWEzteqt&sig=sS0e_s--cl8xXyzMDaTIZ3-Wvck&hl=en&sa=X&ei=201KVfj5EuPR7QaVrYG4Cg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Guanyu Yangjiagou de tudi wenti%2C 1946&f=false

So, can't go much further really. Chee! I mean, Ciao!

Comment: Sounds like an exclamation of discontent. We have 嗤(chi) or 切(qie) in modern Chinese. The meaning and sounding are quite similar. I can't be sure unless I have the original source..

Comment: Looking at that book I see this passage is quoted from a book by Jerome Grieder _Intellectuals and the state in modern China_.  And your book says "romanization modified."  I think that to figure out what Chinese word that is supposed to be, you would have to look at Greider's version.  It could be 嗤 as Wang Dingwei suggests.  But "chee" is not a standard pinyin syllable at all and 嗤 makes little sense here unless it was a "sound effect" in Chinese, of a kind not used much in English.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheebye - it looks like "chee" might be a dialectical shift for the "chou" sound in Mandarin, assuming that "cheebye" is what I think it is.:P

Comment: I am not sure this book would use a Chinese dialect. But I will report the web site mysmu.edu/faculty/jacklee/singlish_C.htm#chee_bye gives the definiton of "chee bye" as Singapore or Hong Kong dialect for 阴物, Mandarin yīn wù, in an obscene sense.

Comment: I think my point is that they're quoting people who might not have been speaking in perfect Mandarin (not to mention people from a while back). That's also interesting... I thought it was 臭(尸穴) in Mandarin

Comment: The website I mentioned says that 臭阴物 is often used.  I am not sure the book the OP is reading is so fastidious about dialect.  And if it is, then it would hardly turn chee into chou in a phrase where chee and chou occur next to each other.  Of course we could postulate some dialect unknown to us in which 臭 is pronounced chee.

Comment: I think the best idea so far is Wang Dingwei's 嗤 as an interjection we could express in English as "chortle."  Here I mean chortle to sound a bit like it chortling, as Wang Dingwei says of 嗤.  The radical on  嗤 suggests it can serve as onomatopoeia.

Comment: maybe you want to check this out: https://shinubiwang.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/urban-dictionary-臭屄-chao-chee-bye/. The problem is 嗤 is a verb (ex 嗤笑), it never seems to be used as an interjection ("嗤!" - does anyone say this?)

Comment: except the chee is actually 膣... interesting... I still think it might be dialect. 嗤 can be used onomatopoetically to describe a sound (ex 聽到"嗤"的一聲) but in that case it has no meaning (as opposed to saying something like "呸！" which is a sound but also has meaning).

Comment: @NeMo what does the [25] footnote refer to exactly?! is what @ ColinMcLarty said, in fact, true? it's from Jerome Grieder Intellectuals and the state in modern China?

Comment: @user3306356  The quote really does not seem to be in Grieder's book.  I may have pursued the wrong footnote 25 in Zarrow's book since I am working from home on (partially available) Google Books copies.  I go in to the university today and if I have time I'll look for library copies.

Comment: I got the book back, and found that's not the right footnote. The citation for the passage I quoted above is footnoted to:
Cited in Joseph Esherick 'Revolution in a Feudal Fortress', pp 362-3

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that may have simply been chi4 "赤" (red), since [赤匪](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%B1%E5%8C%AA) (red bandit) was an derogatory term used by the KMT for the communists.

Comment: Good possibility.